# wstring, wchar_t and fread()

Tags: fread, wchar-t, wstring

I am loading text like this:

```
wstring file;
wchar_t *data = new wchar_t[file_size+1];
fread(data, sizeof(wchar_t), file_size+1, file_stream);
file = data; // I want to create the wstring from the wchar_t data
wcout << data.size() << " " << file;
```

I have 2 problems with this:

1. If I run the program in the Borland C++ Builder, it crashes at wcout (error: "std::bad_alloc") and MVSExpress 2015 doesn't display the string
2. In Borland, the data.size() returns 2203 whereas MVSExpress 2015 shows 4406